# How do you defeat Zeto in Legend of Legaia?

Tags: ps1, legend-of-legaia

I'm currently in the first mist generator castle where Zeto is. How do I beat him easily, as the call wave is very powerful. I'm currently at level 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a video that shows a strategy for level 12 players:

The basic strategy appears to be to focus on defense when Zeto uses Call Wave, as that indicates he'll be doing a powerful attack the next round.  After this attack, focus on healing first before you return to dealing damage.

[This FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197766-legend-of-legaia/faqs/37808) suggests the following combos to deal damage:

> Vahn should simply do: right, right, left, right, right left.
>   Noa has an awesome seven slot combo: down, up, up, up, left, down, right.
>   Gala should just use the Neo Rising move: left, left, right, up left.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the damage and you dont have enough healing stuff, buy deep sea jewel in the monastery (where you got gala) in the kitchen, from the merchandise seller. It costs 3000 or less. Then equip it to all characters and the damage will be lower.